# Experimental evidence for the relic neutrinos

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, big-bang, neutrinos, cosmic-rays

What are the experimental (indirect) evidence for the cosmic neutrino background? Where can I read more about this?

The discussion on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background)  about the C$\nu$B seems to me to be more about the evidence of the number of generation of neutrinos, than about the cosmic neutrino background...

Comment: There is no direct evidence at this time. [We don't even know how to begin.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/26548/520)

Answer (score 1):

We have, at this time, no tools capable of detecting neutrinos at the very low energies of the cosmic neutrino background, and if such tools existed they would have to contend with numerous backgrounds making the experiment ferociously difficult.

Comment: How about indirect evidence, like stated in wikipedia?

Comment: What should I say that isn't in the Wikipedia article? There are three known flavors of neutrinos with some hints that there might be 1--3 sterile flavors. The cosmology is mostly consistent with 3 flavors early and prefers four at later times. (I'm out of my depth on this stuff but naively I would expect the sterile flavors not to contribute early on, and to start to come in at later times.)